# how to integrate getstream.io into cordova / phonegap?

Tags: getstream-io

i am using cordova to build native mobile app. I already have an account in stream.

Currently i need to build a feed like facebook into my app and would like to check UI/UX design layout is included in getstream.io ?

Second, how to integrate getstream.io into my cordova app ? is it just copy the getstream.js into my cordova app ?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any built in user interface, that's entirely up to your application.

We also don't recommend connecting directly to Stream from a mobile application for several reasons. For starters, your API credentials can be easily extracted from the application, which could cost you money if someone abuses your account. Secondly, the socket connections to constantly connect to Stream and read feed updates would use up a lot of battery and data for your users. Better to have your mobile app connect to a back end server, and have that server connect to Stream.